# site is not working properly on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, tablet

Hi I am making a site on price comparison site, site is working properly on desktop but on iPad it is not working properly. there is a shortlist button on product listing page([find link here](http://www.findyogi.com/mobiles)), products on very first row can be shortlisted but other products can't be shortlisted

one more thing, on header there is a white space on right side, how to remove that. please help.

following is the code for listing page unit:

```
<div class="buttons-wrap">
      <div class="btns-show">
         <div class="select-btns cart" title="See Similar Products">
            <p class="sl-btns">View Similar</p>
         </div>
         <div class="select-btns like" title="Add This Product to Shortlist"name="abc">
            <p class="sl-btns">Shortlist</p>
         </div> 
      </div>
</div>
```

`like` is the button for short list, following it JQ code for it:

```
$(this).attr("class")==="select-btns like"?($('.shortlised-prod1').clone(true).find('.prod-thumb img').attr("src",a).end().find('.title-price-wrap a').text(b).attr("ID",id).end().addClass('shortlised-prod').removeClass('shortlised-prod1').insertBefore($('.wrap1'))):null;
```

Comment: @janak shah sir,i don't think very small indentation in JQ code deserves 3 negative points and you didn't even post any answer.

Comment: I've not voted you down.
You seem to be new on stack. Dnt post anything that you are not sure off.